# How to get the data I want according to the rules

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a configuration table like the below, and some users with different attributes. I need to get a configuration data based on user attributes.

I don't know how to implement it, no idea.

[image: configuration data from db table]

Initial code:

```
void Main()
{
    var configList = new List<ConfigEntity>() {
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="37", GoodCode="A", UserType="personal", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Buffalo", Price=37 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="36", GoodCode="A", UserType="personal", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Albany", Price=36 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="35", GoodCode="A", UserType="personal", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="", Price=35 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="34", GoodCode="A", UserType="personal", Country="US", State="", City="", Price=34 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="40", GoodCode="A", UserType="personal", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="Guangzhou", Price=40 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="39", GoodCode="A", UserType="personal", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="", Price=39 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="38", GoodCode="A", UserType="personal", Country="China", State="", City="", Price=38 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="33", GoodCode="A", UserType="personal", Country="", State="", City="", Price=33 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="45", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Buffalo", Price=45 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="44", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Albany", Price=44 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="43", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="", Price=43 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="42", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="US", State="", City="", Price=42 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="48", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="Guangzhou", Price=48 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="47", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="", Price=47 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="46", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="China", State="", City="", Price=46 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="41", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="", State="", City="", Price=41 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="29", GoodCode="A", UserType="", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Buffalo", Price=29 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="28", GoodCode="A", UserType="", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Albany", Price=28 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="27", GoodCode="A", UserType="", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="", Price=27 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="26", GoodCode="A", UserType="", Country="US", State="", City="", Price=26 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="32", GoodCode="A", UserType="", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="Guangzhou", Price=32 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="31", GoodCode="A", UserType="", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="", Price=31 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="30", GoodCode="A", UserType="", Country="China", State="", City="", Price=30 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="25", GoodCode="A", UserType="", Country="", State="", City="", Price=25 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="13", GoodCode="", UserType="personal", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Buffalo", Price=13 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="12", GoodCode="", UserType="personal", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Albany", Price=12 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="11", GoodCode="", UserType="personal", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="", Price=11 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="10", GoodCode="", UserType="personal", Country="US", State="", City="", Price=10 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="16", GoodCode="", UserType="personal", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="Guangzhou", Price=16 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="15", GoodCode="", UserType="personal", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="", Price=15 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="14", GoodCode="", UserType="personal", Country="China", State="", City="", Price=14 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="9", GoodCode="", UserType="personal", Country="", State="", City="", Price=9 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="21", GoodCode="", UserType="organization", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Buffalo", Price=21 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="20", GoodCode="", UserType="organization", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Albany", Price=20 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="19", GoodCode="", UserType="organization", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="", Price=19 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="18", GoodCode="", UserType="organization", Country="US", State="", City="", Price=18 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="24", GoodCode="", UserType="organization", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="Guangzhou", Price=24 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="23", GoodCode="", UserType="organization", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="", Price=23 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="22", GoodCode="", UserType="organization", Country="China", State="", City="", Price=22 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="17", GoodCode="", UserType="organization", Country="", State="", City="", Price=17 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="5", GoodCode="", UserType="", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Buffalo", Price=5 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="4", GoodCode="", UserType="", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Albany", Price=4 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="3", GoodCode="", UserType="", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="", Price=3 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="2", GoodCode="", UserType="", Country="US", State="", City="", Price=2 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="8", GoodCode="", UserType="", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="Guangzhou", Price=8 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="7", GoodCode="", UserType="", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="", Price=7 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="6", GoodCode="", UserType="", Country="China", State="", City="", Price=6 },
        new ConfigEntity { ConfigCode="1", GoodCode="", UserType="", Country="", State="", City="", Price=1 }
    };

    configList.Dump();

}

public class ConfigEntity
{
    public string ConfigCode { get; set; }
    public string GoodCode { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

if GoodCode="A" and user (UserType="personal", Country="US", State="NewYork", City="Albany"), I expect get a data of ConfigCode="36";

if GoodCode="A" and user (UserType="personal", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City=""), I expect get a data of ConfigCode="39";

if GoodCode="A" and user (UserType="personal", Country="", State="", City=""), I expect get a data of ConfigCode="33";

if GoodCode="" and user (UserType="personal", Country="", State="", City=""), I expect get a data of ConfigCode="9";

if GoodCode="B" and user (UserType="", Country="", State="", City=""), I expect get a data of ConfigCode="1";

Comment: Why are there 3 objections? The problem is to find the best matching configuration data.

Answer (score 1):

The place to start is with the simplest thing that will work. In this case, say somebody gives you the following input:

```
{ GoodCode="A", UserType="organization", Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="", Price=47 }
```

So you create a new `ConfigEntity` with that data:

```
var searchFor = new ConfigEntity(
    ConfigCode="??", GoodCode="A", UserType="organization",
    Country="China", State="Guangdong", City="", Price=47);
```

Then you search your list sequentially:

```
ConfigEntity foundItem = null;
foreach (var f in configList)
{
    if (f.GoodCode == searchFor.GoodCode &&
        f.UserType == searchFor.UserType &&
        f.Country == searchFor.Country &&
        f.State == searchFor.State &&
        f.City == searchFor.City)
    {
        foundItem = f;
        break;
    }
}
if (foundItem != null)
{
    // found the item. Do something with it.
}
else
{
    // didn't find the item. Handle the error.
}
```

That isn't the best or most efficient way to do things, but it works. It's a start that you can then improve upon.

Comment: Thank your answer. but it is invalid. I need a method to match one of the best configuration data according to different parameters, only one in priority order, Perhaps,   it cann't be found that the data

Comment: @Net205 Then maybe you need to provide a better explanation of the problem. My understanding of the question you asked indicates that the code I posted will provide a solution. Can you explain why my code does not solve the problem?